# How to check null element in a plsql nested table?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a PLSQL nested table of a record.

```
type rec is record
(a number,
 b number);



type tab is table of rec;

v_tab tab;
```

I am populating this collection from a bulk query;

```
select x,y bulk collect into v_tab from testtable;
```

Now I need to find is there any record in v_tab collection where v_tab.a is null. Can I do it without looping in collection (by using some methods)?

Comment: If your Oracle Version is 12.1 or greater, you can use the TABLE() operator to query your collection, but if an older version then your collection will need to have been defined at the schema level for this to work. See here: http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.ca/2015/04/table-functions-introduction-and.html

Comment: I have defined type at package level and tried the same thing. It's working for me on 12C. But unfortunately I wanted to make it work on 11g. :(

Comment: Unfortunately, with 11G it's either redefine the collection to the schema level or looping through the collection. Wish I had another option for you...

Answer (score 0):

This may be outside the scope of where you want to go, and I don't know your data, but...

What about changing your table type to INDEX BY and use NVL(A, -999) as the index?

Then you could test

```
IF v_tab.EXISTS(-999)
THEN
    -- Handle null value
    ...
END IF;
```